# How to set responsive part of footer icons

Tags: html, css, responsive

I am setting up a responsive footer on my website. It looks almost good, because 90% of the devices set by debbuger display content of footer well, but I do not know what is a good practice for small devices.

I provide few of media icons inside a footer which should forward user for different page. I am using Bootstrap 4 for displaying images in content, and it works perfect. I am working with Django so I cut the html and CSS for each part of a page.

That is how footer html looks like right now:

```html
{% block footer %}
    <footer class="footer">
        <div class="social-media hidden-xs">
            <li>
                <i class="fab fa-facebook-square"></i>
            </li>
            <li>
                <i class="fab fa-instagram"></i>
            </li>
            <li>
                <i class="fab fa-pinterest"></i>
            </li>
            <li>
                <i class="fab fa-linkedin"></i>
            </li>
            <li>
                <i class="fas fa-search-location"></i>
            </li>
        </div>
    </footer>
{% endblock %}
```

And I have that CSS to style it:

```css
.footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 70px;
    background-color: white;

}

.footer .social-media {
    display: flex;
    width: 450px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.footer .social-media > li {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 10px auto;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 10px 10px;
}
```

What is a good practice in creating website with provided footer ? Specify for each devices resolution different style ? Or responsive solution is a good idea ?

Right now on the main page it looks like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nW3b6.jpg "footer with whole page resolution on browser"

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wCzmh.jpg "footer with other smaller resolution on browser"

https://i.stack.imgur.com/yWEYT.jpg "footer with really small resolution"

I would like to achieve result which is mostly practice in webprogramming with a responsive footer parts.

Comment: The question might be closed, because the answer will only be opinion biased. For what it's worth, you could reduce the margin between the li, or add flex-wrap to their container.

Comment: @AmauryHanser Changing margin from auto will not destroy responsiveness ?

Comment: Not if you use mediaqueries. But adding `flex-wrap: wrap;` on `.footer .social-media` should already help you, it will dispatch your icons on two rows when there isn't enough space

Answer (score 1):

Man, this is your solution. Just Change your width properties under .social-media class to max-width. It will work like a charm.

```
 .footer .social-media{
     max-width: 453px;
 }
```